# Make materialize labels move out of input box when input box is filled via javascript

Tags: css, label, materialize

Normally, with [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/), the labels for text input boxes show up inside the input boxes until a user enter selects the box and enters text in it. However, when a box's value is filled via javascript, the label does not move out of the way. It stays in the box and overlaps with the text entered. Is there a way to trigger the label transition with javascript as well, so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

More specifically, if you are using Materialize in Rails with turbolinks enabled, you will find that Materialize form fields which are prefilled with non-empty values are not active on page load.

The following method worked for me:

```
$(function() {
    M.updateTextFields();
});
```

It will add class `'active'` to both corresponding labels and prefix icons.

Comment: Materialize no longer works, you can replace it with `M.updateTextFields();`

Comment: If you don't use jquery:
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // @ts-ignore
  M.updateTextFields();
 });

Answer (score 17):

The label transition behavior is triggered by adding the `active` class to the label's element. Thus, if you make your javascript add that class to the label (e.g. `$('label').addClass('active')`) in addition to filling in the field, the label will transition out of the field just as it would when selected by a user action.

Answer (score 3):

If you use labels, you will use:

```
$("label[for='idTag']").addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 2):

The `document.ready` event only fire once when turbolinks is working, so instead you need to tap into the turbolinks load event.

It happens *so* fast that if you want to see the animation, wrap it in a tiny timeout.

*With timeout/visible animation*

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        M.updateTextFields();
    }, 100);
});
```

*Without timeout/visible animation*

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    M.updateTextFields();
});
```

**Rails 5 with Turbolinks, and Materialize CSS 1.0.0**

Answer (score 1):

Add `class="active"`into the `label` tag associated with the input field.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you can use 
$('#yourInputText').change();

Comment: you have to be more explicit about your answer for the sake of beginners.

Comment: Only yout need is a single line.  $('input').change() or Materialize.updateTextFields(). It's all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using older version (0.x) of Materializecss, use:

```
Materialize.updateTextFields();
```

instead of:

```
M.updateTextFields();
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for solution in ReactJS:

1. link the value property of the input to some value in your Component's state. (*Eg: value={this.state.name}*)
2. Add the line `document.M.updateTextFields()` to the `componentDidMount()` lifeCycle method of your Component.

The above solution helps when there are certain values which need to be prefilled into a Form. (Eg: Update Details Form)